# "not a query" exception while executing query using cx_Oracle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle database and execute a query using cx_Oracle in python with following code

```py
import cx_Oracle

mobileNumber='1234567890'
dbHost='some_value'
dbPortNumber='some_value'
dbUsername='some_value'
dbPasswd='some_value'

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dbHost, dbPortNumber, service_name='ORCL')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=dbUsername, password=dbPasswd, dsn=dsn_tns)
cur=conn.cursor()

query='insert into table_name values ((select max(ID)+1 from table_name),"sms","'+ mobileNumber + '")'
cur.execute(query)

res=cur.fetchall()
print (res)
```

But I am getting following exception when running this code

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 16, in <module>
    result=cur.fetchall()
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query
```

When printing the value of variable **query** I am getting following

```sql
insert into table_name values ((select max(ID)+1 from table_name),"sms","1234567890")
```

Comment: A query begins with `select` and doesn't modify the database. An `insert` doesn't provide any rows you could fetch.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle programmer, but I'm pretty sure it only allows single quotes around strings. Double quotes are for table and column names.

Comment: @Barmar I tried with single quotes also but it is giving same error

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok I understand now but how to get whether the insert statement was successful or not

Comment: What are you expecting to fetch? You didn't select anything, you just inserted. It doesn't return the row that was inserted.

Comment: If it's not successful you'll get an exception signaled when you call `cur.execute()`. Also, you need to call `cur.commit()` to save the change.

Comment: BTW, if you want the `id` column to automatically increment when you add a new row, declare it as a `SEQUENCE`. See https://www.databasestar.com/auto_increment-oracle-sql/

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I dont have DDL access so can't declare it as sequence

Comment: @Barmar with 12.1+ you don't need a sequence to auto-increment.  Use something like `CREATE TABLE itinerary (id NUMBER(11) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1))`

Comment: @harv3 do not concatenate `mobileNumber1` into the statement.  This is a security risk and can give poor performance.  Use a bind variable.  See the note in green at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html

Comment: @ChristopherJones I'm not an Oracle programmer, I googled for the equivalent of auto_increment and that was what I found.